# What software to organize pdfs and references for research?

Tags: software-recommendation

On Windows there are endnote, mendeley, ... On ubuntu, what is the best option to organize references?

Obs.: I'm writting my thesis in latex.

Comment: http://xmodulo.com/reference-management-software-linux.html, http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100706151504485/Bibliography.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software#Operating_system_support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zotero is free, open-source and has excellent documentation. Mendeley also has a Linux desktop client, so you can use that if you prefer.